# Exact Target- Turn off redirects in emails? No tracking needed

Tags: marketing-cloud, weblinks

Is there a way in Exact Target to turn off any links in text emails being changed to exact target redirects? We don't need link tracking and our IT team is being very particular about people getting email messages with links that aren't direct links.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change this setting in both test sends and guided sends. There is a checkbox to toggle this behavior. Also, if you have UTM turned on for your account, you can eliminate those by just removing values on the properties pane.
[[image: Link tracking in sends]]

[image: System generated links in tests]

Comment: Please mark useful if this answer helped or unuseful if it did not.